# remove three digits based on condition in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a sheet with data , i want to remove last three numbers , but in some cells i have text only so i need a formula that remove last three numbers if cell have, For Ex:

```
Cell A                     |    Cell B 
---------------------------------------------
my data row 1 in 123       |  my data row 1 in
----------------------------------------------
this is 2nd row data in 345| this is 2nd row data in
----------------------------------------------
3rd row data               | 3rd row data
```

I tried this code `=LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-3)&""`  and its work if cell have numbers but problem is their when column have no numbers in last this formula remove 3 words from text. so i need formula that remove only last 3 numbers if cell have, otherwise print data as it as in next column , hope understand my question thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether last three characters are numbers, and remove them only if yes:

`=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,3))),A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))`

[image]

Comment: thanks . its work great , thanks for sharing your knowledge